# How can I spread the ToC over two slides in beamer?

Tags: beamer

As I have a rather long Table of Contents in my beamer document (I have four section, each composed of at least five subsections), I'd like to spread it over two slides rather than just one. How can I do that? My code so far:

```
\documentclass[leqno,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphics,bm}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\mathopen{}\mathrm{d}}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%the university of bamberg colors
% colors to be used
\definecolor{fu-blue}{RGB}{0, 51, 102} % blue text
\definecolor{fu-green}{RGB}{153, 204, 0} % green text
\definecolor{fu-red}{RGB}{204, 0, 0} % red text (used by \alert)


%the usage of the colors in special elements
%\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=UBBlack}
%\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{UBBlack}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=fu-blue}

\usepackage[tightpage]{preview}


\setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=black,bg=red!20!green!50!white}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=blue!50!white}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=black,bg=red!70!white}


\AtBeginSection[] 
{ 
\begin{frame}<beamer>{Plan} 
\tableofcontents[currentsection] 
\end{frame} 
} 

\title[SDE]{SDE}
\subtitle{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\author[XXXXXXXXXXXX]{XXXXXXX} 
\institute{XXXXXXXX}
\date{\today}

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertslidenavigationsymbol}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section[Plan]{}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[Introduction]{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
(introduction)
\end{frame}

\section[EDS]{EDS}
\subsection[Définition XXX]{Définition XXX}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Définition XXXX}
bla bla bla bla 
\end{frame}

\subsection[Solution XXXXXXX]{Solution XXX}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Solution XXXX}
bla bla bla bla bla
\end{frame}

\subsubsection[Diverses notions de solutions]{Diverses notions de solutions}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Diverses XXXXXXXXXXX}
\framesubtitle{Solution XXXXXXX}
bla bla bla
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Diverses XXXXX}
\framesubtitle{Solution XXXXX}
bla bla bla
\end{frame}
\subsubsection{Diverses XXXX}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Diverses XXXX}
\framesubtitle{Unicité }
bla bla bla 

\end{frame}

\subsection{Diverses notions d'existence et unicité des solutions }
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Existence et unicité des solutions }
\framesubtitle{Sous Condition de lipschitzienne }
bla bla bla
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Existence et unicité des solutions}
\framesubtitle{Sous Condition de XXXXXXX}
\end{frame}


\section[Diffusion]{Diffusion}
\subsection{Définition d'une diffusion d'Itô}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Définition d'une diffusion d'Itô}
\framesubtitle{Notation}
bla bla bla 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Définition d'une diffusion d'Itô}
bla bla bla 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Flot stochastique}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Flot stochastique}
\framesubtitle{propriété du Flot stochastique}
bla bla bla 
\end{frame}

\subsection{La propriété de Markov}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{La propriété de Markov}
\framesubtitle{Notation}
bla bla bla 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Propriété de Markov}
\framesubtitle{Propriété de Markov version :Faible et Forte}
bla bla 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Semi-groupes et générateurs d'une diffusion d'Itô}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Semi-groupes}
\frametitle{Définition d'un Semi-groupes}
bla bla bla 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Définition d'un Générateur d'une diffusion d'Itô}
\framesubtitle{Notation}
bla bla 
\end{frame}

\subsection{La formule de Dynkin}
\begin{frame}
bla bla bla 
\end{frame}

\section[Simulation]{Simulation}
\subsection{A-1}
\begin{frame}
bla bla bla 
\end{frame}
\subsection{A-2}
\begin{frame}
bla bla bla
\end{frame}
\subsection{A-3}
\begin{frame}
bla bla
\end{frame}
\subsection{A-4}
\begin{frame}
bla bla 
\end{frame}
\subsection{A-5}
\begin{frame}
bla bla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your current code is not compilable. Please make it compilable. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `allowframebreaks` option.
It tells beamer that if the contents do not fit in the current slide it can put the overflowing lines in a separate slide (or more, as needed).
It is very handy for table of contents and bibliographies.

In your case just put

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

If you want to apply this option to the frames generated by

```
\AtBeginSection[] 
{ 
\begin{frame}<beamer>{Plan} 
\tableofcontents[currentsection] 
\end{frame} 
}
```

you have to remove the overlay  as `allowframebreaks` is not compatible with overlays. You can achieve the same effect with

```
\mode<presentation>{
    \AtBeginSection[] 
    { 
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Plan} 
    \tableofcontents[currentsection] 
    \end{frame} 
    } 
}
```

However I do not recommend breaking the toc at every section.
(Actually in my opinion it may be not shown at all, but that's another story)

Comment: Your intention is laudable, but please refrain from altering the code posted in the question, even to make it compilable. If you do, the OP might still be complaining about errors s/he gets with the old code, but that nobody else gets because they are now working from your compilable version of the OP's code. For this reason, I think it's better to leave comments on the question to help the OP make his/her code compilable rather than directly alter the code.

Comment: Thanks.  I fought with this one forever before I found this note. The suggestion does prevent the outline from running off the bottom of the one slide. However, the page break has a weird effect, where the 2nd page out of the TOC is not spaced uniformly top to bottom. It seems as though it is trying to fit as much TOC onto page 1 as possible, and then the things on page 2 are stretched vertically, wide spaces.   Its not bad enough for me to make a new question about it, but I'm mentioning it in case other visitors test this approach.